# String make-up from an array using "foreach" or "for" Loop construct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i need to use a for loop i think so I can access each property in each row in the array to make up my string.

```
  public static string GetHintText(this IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> HintTextString)
  {

    foreach (var part in HintTextString)
    {
      HintText = HintText + "  " + part.Name + "  " + part.IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName + " = " + part.Points;
    }

    return HintText;
  }

  public class UserTrainingPointsDataModel
  {
    public virtual int InteractionType { get; set; }
    public virtual int Points { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName { get; set; }
  }
```

each row constains values:

```
  China Incentive Program  Points For Completing = 50  
  India - Q2 Incentive   Points Per Correct Answer = 50  
  China - Q2 Incentive  Points For Completing = 50  
  India Incentive Program  Points Per Correct Answer = 100  
  India - Q2 Incentive   Points Per Correct Answer = 100
```

`HintTextString` contains 5 rows each with the properties above and i need to make up a string that looks like this:

```
  "Incentive Program: " + part.Name[0] + "  " + part.IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName[0] + " + " + part.Points[0] + 
  "Incentive Program: " + part.Name[1] + "  " + part.IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName[1] + " + " + part.Points[1]
```

etc. So i need a for loop rather? and how would I get the length of HintTextString?
intellisense does not give me that property

The view:

```
 <% if (module.HasAssessment)
 { %>
    <div class="<%: moduleStateClass %>">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="<%: moduleScoreClass %>"><%: module.ModuleScore %></div>
    <% var HintText =  TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelExtentions.GetHintText(module.UserTrainingPoints); %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       <%: Html.GetQTip("training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId , "Incentive program: " + HintText , "training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId , Zinc.Web.Extensions.QTipPosition.Bottom, true, "Module Points") %>
    </script> 
 <% }  %> 
 <% else
    {  %>
 <% var HintText =  TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelExtentions.GetHintText(module.UserTrainingPoints); %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <%: Html.GetQTip("training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId , "Incentive program: "  + HintText ,"training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId , Zinc.Web.Extensions.QTipPosition.Bottom, true, "Module Points") %>   
 </script>
 <% } %>
```

"Action" :

```
  <div class="module-column-content">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Training/Views/Home/Details.ascx", Model); %>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: so you want to return the whole list as one sting

Comment: post the action that generates the result

Comment: Also post the view if possible

Comment: i think you need nested for Loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to return the whole list as one sting in the format you described this should work

```
public static string GetHintText(this IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> HintTextString)
{
    string returnValue = string.Empty;
    foreach (var dataModel in HintTextString)
    {
        returnValue += string.Format("Incentive Program: {0}  {1} + {2}  ", dataModel.Name, dataModel.IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName, dataModel.Points);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

As **Jared** mentioned, if your collection is large you probably want to use `StringBuilder` as is much better on perfromance.

```
public static string GetHintText(this IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> HintTextString)
{
    var returnValue = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var dataModel in HintTextString)
    {
        returnValue.AppendFormat("Incentive Program: {0}  {1} + {2}  ", dataModel.Name, dataModel.IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName, dataModel.Points);
    }
    return returnValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: When doing rapid string manipulation `StringBuilder` should be used...  If there are 5000 items in the array/list this could be very "costly"

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) to construct the text, while iterating on the collection. It's optimized to work with string manipulation functions. If you use simple text adding (`+=`) in looping the performance can get abysmal.

```
public static string GetHintText(this IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> HintTextString)
{
  //format for each item 
  //{Name} {ModuleName} = {Points} <NewLine>
  string lineFormat = "Incentive Program: {0} {1} = {2}\r\n";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var part in HintTextString)
  {
     sb.AppendFormat(lineFormat, part.Name, part.IncentiveTrainingModuleOptionName, part.Points);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Also, if you need the length of the `HintTextString` collection, you can use the [IEnumerable.Count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) extension method.